# ERROR git: ! [rejected] master -> master (fetch first)

Tags: git, github, git-push

Al querer subir código a github por medio de git (linea de comandos) y ejecutar el comando:

```
git push -u origin main
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

```
! [rejected]        main -> main (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/...
```

Encontré una forma de "corregirlo":

```
git pull
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/main main
git pull --allow-unrelated-histories
git push -u origin main
```

Con la cual ya se sube.

¿Hay alguna forma de evitar las lineas anteriores?

Answer (score 0):

antes del git push debes obtener la informacion del estado actual del repositorio remoto siempre, sino hay comflictos, con git pull por ejemplo la obtienes, solo sin git branch ni el resto, luego despliga tus cambios, con git push sin -u origin si la rama la tienes por defecto

Answer (score -1):

### To fix the "git push origin main" problem write:

```
error: falló el empuje de algunas referencias a 'https://github.com/abrishe/Angular-Project.git'
ayuda: Actualizaciones fueron rechazadas porque el remoto contiene trabajo que
ayuda: no existe localmente. Esto es causado usualmente por otro repositorio
ayuda: empujando a la misma ref. Quizás quieras integrar primero los cambios
ayuda: remotos (ej. 'git pull ...') antes de volver a hacer push.
ayuda: Mira 'Notes about fast-forwards' en 'git push --help' para detalles.
```

step 1: `git init`

step 2: `git add .`

step 2: `git status` // you can see which files was modified before "commit"

step 3: `git commit -m "<comment>"`

step 4: `git push origin main -f`

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! La respuesta debe estar en el idioma del sitio. Tradúcela.

Comment: Además... ¿Por qué forzar el _push_? Eso es lo que hace el `-f`.